# Are spaces in enum keys allowed?

Tags: typescript

The following code

```
enum Foo {
  Bar = 1,
  ["Bar Test"] = 3,
}
```

compiles fine in [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwLACgq6gMTjigF4oBGAGmzygG0AiAIQENUAVYAZwBcGBdUlABM2AL7YgA) but inserting it into a clean create-react-app project produces a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: <...>\ts-test\src\App.tsx: Unexpected token (7:2)
```

Is this valid TS? Is there some tsconfig variable or version that allows it?

Comment: Why do you want this? It's like asking for a space in a variable name ─ it shouldn't be necessary because it should never be exposed to the user anyway.

Comment: Yes, spaces in enum keys are allowed in TypeScript; there was once a bug fix at [ms/TS#40679](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40679) specifically to make sure they were supported.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer.  If not and you need someone to explain what's going on with create-react-app you might want to tag the question as such so that someone who knows about that might be more likely to see it.

Comment: @kaya3 it's a little quirky use case, I used enum to mirror names used in another project, it was pretty convenient to use them to convert from numerical ID to string and vice versa. But some of the names started having spaces in them so I ran into this issue. I could just use regular objects instead I suppose.

Comment: @jcalz thanks, ye that's what I wanted to know. I do wonder what makes CRA not recognize it (different version of TS?) but it's not very important to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces are indeed allowed in [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) keys; they are not required to be valid [identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier).

This doesn't seem to be explicitly documented anywhere obvious (the [outdated spec section on enum declarations](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3821ef011ada48c14e07e3124c6502a44a3e3856/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#a7-enums) does indicate that the key could be any non-computed property name, which *may* be an identifier, but could also be a string literal).

However, there was a bug reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#40152](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40152) and fixed at [microsoft/TypeScript#40679](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40679)  whereby enums with keys that were invalid as identifiers were causing the compiler to produce invalid JavaScript (presumably they had just assumed that keys would be valid identifiers).  The fix was to change the emitted JavaScript to handle invalid identifier enum keys.  That implies that enums with such keys are intentionally supported.  Otherwise, the fix would be to make the TypeScript compiler reject such enum keys.

So it's safe to say that these are supported.